# I really need to restore my laptop

Tags: restore

I really need to restore my laptop back to factory settings because I screwed it up using ubuntu. How can I restore it?

Comment: Just make a fresh install of Ubuntu and everything will be fine! I do it every 6 months! Good luck.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you want.  If you want it restored to factory settings, what were those settings?  Do you want to keep Ubuntu and fix it, or what?  We need some more information from you.

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall Ubuntu through a LiveDVD/LiveUSB, when you start the install processes you will be asked if you want to "Reinstall Ubuntu", and keep your files, or "Erase Ubuntu and reinstall" getting everything fresh and new (Everything will be deleted).

I recommend you to Erase your Ubuntu and reinstall, deleting everything, although if you need to keep your files and there is no way to backup them, then just choose to reinstall Ubuntu.

Things should be solved then!